# Output from DB2 stored procedure is null

Tags: php, sql, stored-procedures, db2

I'm trying to figure out why the output of my stored procedure returns null, even though the insert within the procedure is taking place

First, my parameters for the procedure:

```
PARAMS:

IN IN_FIRST_NAME,
IN IN_LAST_NAME,
OUT OUT_V_R_ID
```

So here's the routine which calls an insert and then I'm trying to set my output variable to the created V_R_ID, which is the records' ID

```sql
P1 : BEGIN ATOMIC

DECLARE V_H_ID INTEGER DEFAULT 0 ;
DECLARE V_R_ID VARCHAR ( 20 ) ;
DECLARE V_ROW_CHANGE_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP ;

SELECT CAST ( NEXT VALUE FOR SCHEMA . H_ID_SEQ AS VARCHAR ( 20 ) )
INTO V_R_ID
FROM SYSIBM . SYSDUMMY1 ;

CALL SCHEMA . INSERT_RECORD ( V_R_ID
, IN_FIRST_NAME
, IN_LAST_NAME
) ;

SET OUT_V_R_ID = V_R_ID ;

END P1
```

Then, in PHP, I'm calling the function with the form input first and last name, and setting $out2 as the variable for my output. The dump die just prints null though

```
function createJobTitleToDealerContact($firstName,$lastName){

    $stmt = \DB::connection('odbc')->getPdo()->prepare('CALL SCHEMA.CREATERECORD(?,?,?)'); 

    $stmt->bindParam(1, $firstName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $lastName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $out2, PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);

    $stmt->execute();
    dd($out2);
}
```

Am I just calling it incorrectly in the PHP?

Comment: Shouldn't your 3rd bindParm call use 3 instead of 6? `$stmt->bindParam(3, $out2, PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);`

Comment: Sorry, I fixed that but still same issue. That was a carryover typo from my source code

Comment: @Dave so the procedure does execute successfully, it's just not returning the id back in the output

Comment: If you can prove (with debugging) that the `SET OUT_V_R_ID = V_R_ID ` *executes* and OUT_V_R_ID is varchar(20), then try `  $stmt->bindParam(3, $out2, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_OUTPUT, 20);`

Comment: I don't have an instance of DB2 to test with but after you execute your call you need to do another query to select the output. Using the following code results in the single value I put into my test procedure. `$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8mb4','user','pass');
$thecall = $db->prepare('CALL test(@out2)');
$thecall->execute();
$dosel = $db->query('select @out2');
$response = $dosel->fetchColumn();`.

Comment: @TomN. Did you define the `OUT_V_R_ID` parameter as `OUT` in the `CREATE PROCEDURE SCHEMA.CREATERECORD` statement? Lile `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CREATERECORD (
  IN  IN_FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(20)
, IN  IN_LAST_NAME  VARCHAR(20)
, OUT OUT_V_R_ID    VARCHAR(20)
)`

Comment: @MarkBarinstein yes I did but thank you. I think i resolved it by casting the output as a varchar. It's now dumping the ID

Comment: @TomN. ... In future, please include the `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE` line which specifies in/out params and their data types which we could help diagnose your issue.